# Magento 2.2.2 display catalog price rule on category page for configurable items

Tags: magento2, catalog-price-rules

I have a magento 2.2.2 based website and the site consists mostly of configurable items.

My issue is when I create a catalog price rule when you go to a category page it just shows the price of the item and it is only when you click on a product and view the product detail page and select a configurable item do you then see the discounted price.

So is there any off the shelf/default magento2 setting to make the category pages show the discounted price?

Comment: Unfortunately not I did this for a client last week basically calling the group price of cheapest simple item which works similar to what you are after